# What is the JSON Data?

Tags: php, json

I coded a script longago which is extremely popular however i am about to role out a update using the clever in-app-auto update feature i coded. Now the question is i have lost the JSON data i was displaying to the code which it then decodes and reads and gets the relevant content.

Here is a snippet:

```
function check_update(){
    $v = isset($_GET['v']) ? $_GET['v']:11;
    $reqUrl = "http://myserver.myhost.com/api/update/?" . "v=" . $v;
    return json_decode(@file_get_contents($reqUrl));
}

function updatefunction(){
$updateResult = check_update();
print $updateResult->content . "\n\r";
}
echo updatefunction();
```

I have added the "echo updatefunction();" as a debug test for me to see if it is getting the correct data.

Now my question is what should the **$reqUrl** be showing for this script to echo some content ?

Thanks

Comment: no the URL is irrelevant i would like to know what JSON is needed to show, for this code to echo the content.

Comment: $reqUrl could contain ANYTHING for something to appear on screen, aslso no need for the echo, when the function has a print